# The Sum of 5 Consecutive Integers is 505, what is the Third number in this Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

So I've never covered this and I'm a bit confused.

$$x + (x+1) + (x+2) + (x+3) + (x+4)$$

So $5x + 10 = 505$ which equals $x = 99$. So isn't the third integer $2$? Which would mean that it equals to $1 + 2 + (99) = 102$? Why is the correct answer $101$, only taking into account the third integer ignoring its sequence @_@?

Comment: You are correct that $x = 99$. Just note that of the $5$ numbers you listed, $x+2$ would be the third

Comment: If you make the numbers $x-2, x-1, x, x+1, x+2$ the calculation is easier - a trick often useful when you have a finite arithmetic progression with an odd number of terms. For example, it is sometimes required to compute the product, and this is much easier with the form I suggest.

Comment: Of $5$ consecutive integer the third will automatically be the mean.

Comment: It is very helpful to write down the definition of your variables to avoid confusion.  In this case, you could write "Let $x$ be the first of the integers.  Then the integers are $x, x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4,$ which sum to $5x+10$"  Then when you solve for $x$, which you have done correctly, you would know what to do to get the desired answer to the problem.  In this case the third number is $x+2$, so the answer is $101$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you've setup the problem, we know that the first integer is $x$, the second is $x+1$, the third is $x+2$, and so forth. Since you found $x$ to be $99$, then the third integer is
$$x+2=99+2=101.$$

Comment: Yeah. But I mean logically it asks us for the third number in this sequence. So the answer would be 2, but how can we just add that ignoring the sequence that led the third integer to be 2? Bit confused here @_@. My input was 102 since I couldn't figure out why I would ignore the first integer here.

Comment: @EliS. What do you mean by "the answer would be $2$"? The answer to what question?

Comment: The first number is $x$.  The second number is $x+1$.  The third number is $x+2$.  Since we want to know what the third number is, once we find $x$, we add 2.

Comment: Sorry English is not my first language. It asks for the third integer in this sequence which would equal 2. But how can we just add that to 99 ignoring the fact that the third integer came after the second one which would both equal 3 + 99 = 102.

Comment: @EliS. The third integer in the sequence is $x+2$, not $2$. Your sequence of integers is
$$ x,\,x+1,\,x+2,\,x+3,\,x+4.$$

Comment: Oh I understand you now John.

Answer (score 2):

In overly pedantic detail, you might think of the problem this way:

We have five consecutive integers that add to 505.  Let the five numbers be $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $e$.  Since they are consecutive integers, we may assume that they are ordered $a < b < c < d < e$, from which it follows that
\begin{align}
b &= a+1 \\
c &= b+1 = (a+1) + 1 = a+2 \\
d &= c+1 = (a+2) + 1 = a+3 \\
e &= d+1 = (a+3) + 1 = a+4.
\end{align}
We want to find the third integer in this sequence, which means that we are trying to find the value of $c$.  We already know that $c = a+2$, so we can, instead, try to find $a$, then add 2 to that in order to get $c$.  But the numbers add to 505, so we have
\begin{align}
505 &= a + b + c + d + e \\
&= a + (a+1) + (a+2) + (a+3) + (a+4) \\
&= 5a + 10.
\end{align}
This implies that
$$ 5a = 495 \implies a = 99. $$
But remember that we were trying to find $c$, not $a$, and that $c=a+2$.  Therefore the third integer in the sequence is
$$ c = a+2 = 99+2 = 101.$$

---

It might be simpler to work this way:  $c$ is the third integer in the sequence.  Since we want to find $c$, we should write the other four integers in terms of $c$.  As above
\begin{align}
d &= c+1 \\
e &= d+1 = (c+1) + 1 = c+2,
\end{align}
since $d$ and $e$ are the next two consecutive integers.  To get $a$ and $b$, we have to count down, instead of up, which gives us
\begin{align}
b &= c-1 \\
a &= b-1 = (c-1)-1 = c-2.
\end{align}
Then we have
\begin{align}
505 &= a + b + c + d + e \\
&= (c-2) + (c-1) + c + (c+1) + (c+2) \\
&= 5c,
\end{align}
which implies that $c = 101$.

Comment: Thanks Xander, I just had it in my head that, to get to the integer x + 2, you would need to cross x + 1. So ignoring x + 1 in this equation to present the result as 101 instead of 102 didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

*A very simple variant:*

Let $a_1$ the first integer, $a_5$ the fifth. The sum $S$ of these integers is
$$S=5\cdot\frac{a_1+a_5}2=505, \quad\text{whence }\quad a_3=\frac{a_1+a_5}2=101.$$